# Termical printer cut the text vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm developing an aplication that prints a list of products. I was looking information and i use this code to print:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Products", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 25, YPosition)
YPosition += 80
e.Graphics.DrawString(fechaHora, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 25, YPosition)
YPosition += 40
e.Graphics.DrawString("Nmp: " + npedido, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 25, YPosition)
YPosition += 40

If special <> "" Then
      e.Graphics.DrawString(special, printFontTitulo, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 425, YPosition)
      YPosition += 40
End If

e.Graphics.DrawString("==============================================", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 25, YPosition)
YPosition += 40
e.Graphics.DrawString("==============================================", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 25, YPosition)
YPosition += 40

For i = 0 To lst_products.Items.Count - 2
     e.Graphics.DrawString(lst_products.Items.Item(i) + " (" + lst_price.Items.Item(i) + ")", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 25, YPosition)
     YPosition += 40
Next
```

the problem starts when the list of products is arround 20 products, the heigth of the paper is similar to an A4 and stop printing.

I don't know if the problem is the printer or my code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i have tried to use that but happend exactly the same. :S